# How do I understand 能 in 请问几天能到?

Tags: grammar

In the following dialogue:

> A: 小姐， 我想机一个包裹。
>   B: 请问，寄到哪儿? 寄什么?
>   .........

Then later A asks:

> 请问几天**能**到?

What is 能 here, I cannot find the grammar.

In my books 能 is for permission, to be able to do something, ‘be possible’ also express possibility, in the sense of someone being able to do something on a particular occasion.

But in this case is a question for the future, how long does it take the packet to reach. Can you not use 会?If you use 能, what is the exact grammar point?

Comment: 急什么, also, seems wrong.

Comment: some omissions here, ```(这个包裹)几天能到(目的地)```. And mistakes for the first sentence, which should be ```我"想寄"一个包裹```

Answer (score 2):

> A: "小姐， 我想寄一个包裹。" (Miss, I want to mail a parcel)
>
> B: "请问寄到哪儿? 寄什么?" (May I ask, where are you mailing it to? And what you are mailing?)
>
> .......
>
> A: "请问几天能到?" (may I ask, in how many days can it arrive?)

能 = can ; 到 = arrive

> 几天**能**到? =  **can** arrive in how many days?

会 = would/will

> 几天**会**到? = **would/will** arrive in how many days?

Comment: A question if you have the time: in 粤语 does 我 sound like 'low'? In pinyin they write ngo5.

Comment: '我' doesn't sound like 'low'

Comment: Yes I wrote wrong some characters. Now they are right. But the 能 is the question. Does it mean. How long does it take the parcel to arrive¿. Why use 能？ what does it really mean¿

Answer (score 0):

A 小姐， 我相机一个包裹。
Miss, I wanna camera a parcel.

Tang Ho is probably right, you may mean 想寄：
Miss, I wanna send a parcel.

B 请问，寄到哪儿? 急什么? 
Where d'you wanna send it to? Need fast delivery?

Then later A asks:

请问几天能到?
How long before it arrives?

Use 能 or 会：一样的。

请问几天会到?
How long before it arrives?

Comment: Yes I wrote wrong some characters. Now thy are ok. Why use能 to say hoe long¿ is there a grammar for that¿

Comment: 能 or 会 here means "able to" So, 能到 or 会到 simply  means "...able to arrive" Or if you wish to be pedantic, you could even say 能够到达